# Python IDE for Windows 8 RT?

Tags: python, ide, windows-rt

Is there a python ide for Windows RT? Or is there a way to download 3rd party IDEs that can work on RT? There is one in the market place called "Python 3 for Metro" but it is nothing like the IDE I use on my desktop called "PyScripter".

Anyone have any advice? Maybe decent online IDEs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [Code Writer](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/code-writer/5149f454-94a7-40bc-90ef-eafd38355079).

Answer (score 1):

Time is gone a whlie.
But now it's possible, to run Python 2.7 on Surface RT.
All what you have to do is to set you Surface rt in developermode, as followed:

https://github.com/VNNGYN/Windows-RT-8.1-Development-Tool

you than get Surface rt run in test mode.
In testmode you can sign all the already ported application, there are avaible on net.
To sign the appclication with a cert, you can use:

https://github.com/VNNGYN/Windows-RT-8.1-Development-Tool/wiki/How-do-I-sign-an-application%3F

than all the application, like python 2.7 can run under Standard mode.

https://github.com/VNNGYN/Windows-RT-8.1-Development-Tool/wiki/How-do-I-sign-an-application%3F

and there you will find Notepad++, which is the best to generate python scripts

enjoy